# Compile Error : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I'm trying to build Boost libraries,and I get these message:

The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

```
C:\local\boost_1_60_0
```

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

```
C:\local\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib
```

Since I don't know how to add path to compiler, I just type:

> mingw32-make -I C:\local\boost_1_60_0 -f makefile

to compile my c++ program , but enconter an fatal error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxcx2.png)

any help will be greatly appreciated , Thanks!

Comment: [`-I <path>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html), but SO is really not a substitute for a quick look at the documentation.

Comment: (and `-L <path>` for the linker)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
gcc -Iyourincludepath -Lyourlibpath -lyourlib
```